# Magento : Disable and Enable Cache Programattically

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have execute below code before execute some content(i.e Menu) for disable cache on page

```
$types = Array(
          0 => 'evolved'
        );

$allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();

$updatedTypes = 0;
    foreach ($types as $code) {

        if (!empty($allTypes[$code])) {

            $allTypes[$code] = 0;
            $updatedTypes++;

        }

    }

Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
```

It disabled cache [image]
Now I want to enable after some content(i.e Menu) programmatically.
How can i achieve it? 
Above code is correct or minimization possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the script for you. You can set  to `$allTypes[$code] = 1;` If you want to `enable cache`

```
<?php

    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

    require_once $mageFilename;

    umask(0);
   Mage::app('admin');

Mage::app()->cleanAllSessions();
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
Mage::app()->cleanCache();

$types = Array(
          0 => 'config', 
          1 => 'layout',
          2 => 'block_html', 
          3 => 'translate', 
          4 => 'collections',
          5 => 'eav',
          6 => 'config_api',
          7 => 'fullpage',
          8=>'config_api2'                    
        );

 $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();

$updatedTypes = 0;
foreach ($types as $code) {



        $allTypes[$code] = 0; // here you can  set 1 If you want to enable
        $updatedTypes++;


    $tags = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($code);
}
    Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
    echo "done ";
```

Comment: It works only for disable cache. I have tried this script run in root folder

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Did you change the value =1 as I have suggested ?

Comment: yes i have changed it 1

Comment: Not working for me. Please give any another solution.

Comment: i have checked $allTypes[$code] = 0; // here you can  set 1 If you want to enable. Not working for me.

Comment: I have updated script, please check If you want to enable then set 1 and iF you want to disable then set 0. It's working fine in my magento setup. @KetanKpBorada :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Below code is tested and it worked.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('core/cache');
$options = $model->canUse();

foreach($options as $option=>$value) {
    $options[$option] = 1;
}

$model->saveOptions($options);
```

If you want to disable the cache just change the below line.

```
$options[$option] = 0;
```

Hope this helps.

> NOTE : For the sake of simplicity just wrap above code with a function
>   declaration and pass a boolean parameter which will set to
>   `$options[$option]` variable. See the below example.

```
public function enableAllCaches($model, $enable) 
{    
    $options = $model->canUse();

    foreach($options as $option=>$value) {
        $options[$option] = 1;
    }

    $model->saveOptions($options);
} 


public function test() 
{
    // Create the model object
    $model = Mage::getModel('core/cache');

    // Enable all cache types
    $this->enableAllCaches($model, 1);

    // Do your stuff here

    // Disable all cache types
    $this->enableAllCaches($model, 0);
}
```

> UPDATE : Assume you want to enable/disable full_page_cache type only.
>   See the updated code below.

```
    public function enableCacheType($model, $enable, $cacheType) 
    {    
        $options = $model->canUse();
        foreach($options as $option=>$value) {
            // Update the full page cache type
            if($option == $cacheType) {
                $options[$option] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        $model->saveOptions($options);
    } 


    public function test() 
    {
        // Create the model object
        $model = Mage::getModel('core/cache');
        $cacheType = 'full_page';

        // Enable the cache type
        $this->enableCacheType($model, 1, $cacheType);

        // Do your stuff here

        // Disable the cache type
        $this->enableCacheType($model, 0, $cacheType);
    }
```

Comment: hello @Sukeshini i want to do it for only one cache type that **evolved** please update your answer

Comment: @KetanKp Borada : See the update